# Stereochemistry of the product of crotonic acid with bromine

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, c-c-addition

Is there a a simple rule for determining the stereochemistry for the product of a reaction between an unsymmetrical alkene like (2*E*)-but-2-enoic acid and bromine (*anti* reaction)?

[image: Reaction between crotonic acid and bromine]

If it's an *anti* reaction, does that mean that I just need to put each bromine atom on a carbon, which makes the two carbons of the double bond different configurations, like carbon 2 *R* and carbon 3 *S*, or the other way around?

And if it's a *syn* reaction, does that mean that the two carbons in the product need to be same configuration? If that's the case, I get it. But if it's not, how would you decide how would the bromines go in without models?

Last but not least, in the second part I need to do an elimination (I made this question by the way to understand this concept), how would I know if the product is *E*/*Z*?

Comment: As far as I remember, bromine water is used instead of just bromine though I am not sure if water has any effect on the reaction.

Comment: it's just Br2/CCl4 , no water. but same logic.